# Asp.net Client - Server POST and Response (405 Method Not Allowed)

Tags: c#, asp.net, post

Why doesn't my server return the same value to the client as he sends?

On the server my ApiController looks like that:

```
public void Post(byte[] value)
    {
        Request.CreateResponse<byte[]>(HttpStatusCode.OK, value);
    }
```

- Shouldn't it return the data from POST to the client? 
And on the client side I've got:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] value = { 16, 32 };

    client.UploadDataCompleted += delegate
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(response));
    };

    response = client.UploadData("http://localhost:52117/", value);
}
```

The error message:

> The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

I just started with ASP.net. I am trying to make it work for hours now lol.

I've tried to follow tutorial with products and stuff, but it's not even similar.

Edit:
I even tried this thing [**Here**](http://www.asp.net/posters/web-api/asp.net-web-api-poster.pdf) where it says:

> The return value from the  action is converted to an 
>   HttpResponseMessage.
>
> If return type is  HttpResponseMessage,  pass through *(as response to client)*.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(byte[] value)
{
    var msg = new HttpResponseMessage();
    msg.Content = new ByteArrayContent(value);
    return msg;
}
```

Nothing works..

Comment: do you need to be authorized to reach that controller's action?  Have you tried looking at your request via [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)?

Comment: @Jonesy No, it's just POST client <-> server data exchange. Whenever client POSTs server, it returns the same data to him. I don't know how to create response. I thought when client POSTs server, server can POST response at him. Can't it?

Comment: I tried with:
`public HttpResponseMessage Post(byte[] value)
{
var msg = new HttpResponseMessage();
msg.Content = new ByteArrayContent(value);
return msg;
}` just like they said [Here](http://www.asp.net/posters/web-api/asp.net-web-api-poster.pdf) and it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

you might missing something

Refer to this link for more idea, https://trentgardner.net/net/asp-net-webmethods-with-jquery-and-ajax/

try

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public void Post(byte[] value)
    {
        Request.CreateResponse<byte[]>(HttpStatusCode.OK, value);
    }
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, 405 method not allowed. I have no idea, searched all over google.

Comment: have you try a simple hello world sample in the link that I provide and see if it works?

Comment: Actually, there's a jquery and I don't need this. I don't even want the server to be accessed with browsers. Just plain POST from clients and responses from server.